# Horner's rule in C++

Tags: c++, math

While trying to evaulate polynomials using [Horner's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) I have a sample code segment like so:

```
int Horner( int a[], int n, int x )
{
    int result = a[n];
    for(int i=n-1; i >= 0 ; --i)
        result = result * x + a[i];
    return result;
}
```

I understand that `a` is an array of coefficients and that `x` is the value that I would like to evaluate at. My question is what is the `n` for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

n is the degree of the polynome (and a polynome of degree n, aside from 0 which is kind of special, has n+1 coefficients, so size of array = n+1, n = size of array - 1)

Answer (score 4):

n is the size of the array

Comment: -1: n is not the size of the array. Horner's rule is for a polynomial of order n and so has n+1 coefficients. The code uses a[n] which is a big hint that n is _not_the size of the array. n is the order of the polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

'n' is index of the last element in the array. Therefore, n is one less than the size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

The code appears to be incorrect. The statement:

```
int result = a[n];
```

should fail if n is size of the array... If n is the size of the array minus 1, then it will work but the contract of the function is very strange in this case. It is impossible to pass empty array to the function, which is not generic and requires additional checking on caller's side.

Comment: n is not the size of the array; it is the order of the polynomial.  A polynomial of order n has n+1 coefficients, hence n+1 elements are in the coefficient array.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the language does not provide native support for getting the length of an array.  Because of that, code must often maintain a separate variable that holds the length.  In this example, the n parameter tells the Horner function how many elements are in the array.

In C++ it's idiomatic to pass the number of elements.  Since arrays are 0 based, the last element of the array is `arr[n-1]`.

Comment: -1: The n parameter tells the function what the order of the polynomial is and from that it works out what the size of the array is. The function signature has been chosen from a mathematical perspective rather than a pure C++ one.