# Horner's Rule C/C++ Using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I learned about Horner's Rule here for the first time: 
[Horner's rule in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697683/horners-rule-c)
Since I am learning about recursion ATM, I was wondering if it is possible to implement this algorithm using recursion ?

```
int HornerR( int a[], int n, int x, int index )
{
    if (index==n) return a[n];
    else  
        return x*HornerR(a,n ,x,index+1) + a[index];
}
```

I think it's only possible with a fourth parameter.

Comment: yeah that should be possible to write with recursion give it a try. If you have an issue you can ask another question (or edit this one) and go from there.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to implement that without the index parameter...??

Comment: Actually that was exactly the same thing I came up with and it seems to work. If there is a way without the fourth parameter I didn't come up with it.

Comment: The only reason for the parameter `n` is that there is no length function for an array in `C` in `Java` this would be 3 parameters and the loop version would be 2. I think the extra parameter is necessary.

Comment: Makes sense. I somehow have to come up with a solution that doesn't use the index parameter. It must be possible I guess

Comment: You could use a sentinel value (i.e. an integer within the array that indicates you have reached the end of the array), such as -1, but you have to use a value that is fully distinguishable from all other data. If all integer values are accepted by your `HornerR` function then you cannot use a sentinel value.

Comment: It's part of an assignment that uses 3 recursive functions and this is the last missing piece.

Comment: can you use 'static int' declaration inside your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with pointer arithmetic:

1. Base Case at the end of array (check n) return constant parameter
2. Recursive Case return current cell added to variable multiplied recursive call
3. Recursive Call move the array to next cell and update the counter (n)

Basically this lets you calculate the index variable by moving the array to the next position and sending that (and always using the first cell) instead of sending the whole array every time

Comment: @JerryCoffin I changed it to a how to.

Comment: Yup -- much better (at least IMO).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I've been thinking about it on and off since he first asked the question and got a little excited when I figured it out.

Comment: I can't blame you -- it is a rather neat little trick. Looking at my answer, although the solution had in mind was essentially the same, I may have been just a little *too* vague -- it might not be enough to lead to the answer, except (maybe) for somebody who could figure it out on their own pretty quickly and easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the function as follows with 3 arguments in function, provided, the array pi contains the coefficients from highest degree to 0 from index 0 to degree+1. Ex for 3x^2 + 2x^1 + 1  => pi[3] = { 3,2,1}

```
int compute_by_horner(int *pi, int degree, int x)
{
int i, j;

if (degree == 0)
{
    return pi[0];
}

return compute_by_horner(pi, degree-1, x) * x + pi[degree];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing an index, think of `a` as a pointer (since it is). Along with that, you'll want to decrement `n`, and keep track of whether it's been reduced to zero yet, rather than keeping track of whether `index==n`.